# Best learning resources for continuous integration tools like Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, python, shell-script

I am a .NET developer , I have decided to learn DevOps continuous integration tools.

One of my folk asked me to learn below tools and language:

1. Jenkins
2. Shell Scripting
3. Python

I have found below learning resources to be usefull.

**Free Videos**

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7-U1_E_j3w
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=89yWXXIOisk&t=89s

**Free Course**

1. https://www.udacity.com/course/intro-to-devops--ud611

**Paid Course**

1. https://www.udemy.com/the-complete-jenkins-course-for-developers-and-devops/

**Training Materials**

https://gist.github.com/ssmythe/ae1449b116ece85dc10d

Is their any other resources available by which one can master Jenkins and continuous integration ?

Any resource available to get started shell scripting and Python language ?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the  resources which might be useful for . continuous integration 
Below . you might be visited but as novice . it will be easy to understand.

jenkins:-

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jenkins/jenkins_git_setup.htm

Shell Scripting :-
 I would . suggest . to start with basic unix commands  like . cp,mv, file related and . permissions etc.. (Basic stuff).

Its good to have . some practise  on the system so that you can  get an Idea . Because as a Devops engineer we should be strong enough on Basic . stuff.

Comment: what about python , is there any good resource to start with basics ?

Comment: Yes , here are the below . links  for Python . i.e . https://www.learnpython.org/ . , https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/